# Connecting points by their ends in ggplot2 chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I am currently working with ggplot2 to create a chart where I need to connect points by their ends, similar to the example image provided below:

[image: Desired outcome example]

To illustrate the issue, consider the following simple code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(day=1:5, sales=c(10, 7, 5, 4, 3))

# Plotting
p1 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(day)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = sales), linetype = 2, linewidth = 0.25) +
  geom_point(aes(y = sales), size = 9, shape = 95) +
  
  theme_minimal()

p1
```

The resulting plot is shown here:

[image: Resulting plot]

As one can see, the line connects points by their center.

While using `position = position_nudge` can "shift" the line with respect to the x-axis, for example, it does not achieve the desired outcome.

```
p2 <- df %>% ggplot(aes(day)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = sales), linetype = 2, linewidth = 0.25, position = position_nudge(x = -0.155)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = sales), size = 9, shape = 95) +
  
  theme_minimal()

p2
```

[image: Undesired outcome]

Do you have any suggestions on how I can connect the points as shown in the example image? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder whether in the example chart, the points are supposed to convey (1) a series of consecutive x-values with the same y-value, or (2) whether the author simply chose a rather strange shape to represent a single point. If (1) then you could just use `geom_point()` without a shape parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with `geom_segment()`, but you have to define the start and end of each segment.  The start could be the (`day`, `sales`) pair, but you'll need to subtract the relevant amount from `day` to put it at the left edge of the point.  You could then have the line run to `lag(day)` and `lag(sales)`, again, making sure that you add the appropriate amount to `lag(day)` to put the segment at the right edge of the point. I used .125 and .075, respectively.  It may take a bit of trial and error to figure out the exact right values.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(day=1:5, sales=c(10, 7, 5, 4, 3)) %>%
  mutate(y_start = sales, 
         y_end = lag(sales),
         x_start = day-.1, 
         x_end = lag(day) + .075) 


df %>% ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=day, y = sales), size = 9, shape = 95) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x_start, y=y_start, xend=x_end, yend = y_end), linetype=2) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>